# Confused by Gothon exercise game Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

From learningpythonthehardway, I've reached the text adventure game and I had a few codes that I understand what they execute, but I don't understand how. Below is the whole code I made smaller into a single .py file:

```
from sys import exit 
from random import randint

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This isn't configured yet. Subclass and implement enter()"
        exit(1)

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Something."
    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "shoot!":
        print "Something something."

        return 'death'


class Death(Scene):

    dead = [
    "You died. That sucks ...",
    "You shouldn't have died here...that was dumb.",
    "You L00se.",
    "Even a cow's moo sounds smarter than you."
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.dead[randint(0, len(self.dead)-1)]
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map #sets scene_map from the a_map variable

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()#sets aMap.opening_scene() and initiates CentralCorridor
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished') #for the last win scene Finished()
        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter() #if scene's not last, call enter() of current scene to next scene name
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)#Set current_scene to instance of scene_map with self, next_scene_name as parameters

        current_scene.enter()

class Map(object): #initially central_corridor

    scenes = {  
        'central_corridor':CentralCorridor(),   
        'death':Death(),
        }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scenes = start_scene #central_corridor


    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name) #sets CentralCorridor() to val
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scenes) #returns val from 
                                            #next_scene which is 
                                            #CentralCorridor()


a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

In this code, I have a few things I don't get (bear with me.)

1. How does " return 'death' " under the CentralCorridor class refer to the dictionary down in Map class's scenes, and return Death class? When I type shoot! it seems to go through the Engine class and execute the current_scene.enter() but I haven't called the Engine class's play function anywhere in the CentralCorridor class.
2. In the Map class's opening_scene function, how exactly is
   return self.next_scene(self.start_scenes) working??? I know what it does, but the self.next_scene(self.start_scenes) bit is slightly confusing me.

Thank you for anyone explaining this!

Answer (score 2):

I have also just reached this exercise few days ago in the book and spent some time looking for answer. This website is really nice tho'. Let me try to explain, as it strengthens my understanding. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong at any point.

Answering your question, I might as well explain the whole thing starting with:

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

a_map is-a Map that takes 'central corridor' as parameter.

In class Map (read the # comment)

```
def __init__(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scenes = start_scene  #start_scene is set to 'central corridor'

def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name) #get() narrows the search in the library scenes.
    return val #return and pass to next_scene as a method.
def opening_scene(self):
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scenes) #return and pass to opening_scene
```

As self.start_scene was set as parameter 'central corridor', opening_scene will search 'central corridor' in the scenes library located in class Map by the method stated in next_scene, which is get() a function used to locate things in the library. Continue on...

```
a_game = Engine(a_map)
```

a_game is-an Engine that takes a_map as parameter, while a_map takes 'central corridor' as a parameter. Thus a_game takes 'central corridor' as a parameter as well. Logic A=B and B=C thus A=C, and also a_game has access to both class Map and Engine as inheritance. You can read about it in the next chapter in the book learningpythonthehardway after this chapter.

In class Engine (read the # comment)

```
def __init__(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map #self.scene_map has set to 'central corridor'
def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene() #set current_scene by calling the function opening_scene which was explained in class Map, accessible by a_game
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished') #set last_scene by searching scene in class Map.
    #I didn't see any 'finish' scene in map. I think you should have added it in scenes.
```

**Note Here!** you will get a return from the enter function.

```
    while current_scene != last_scene: #enters the while loop!! This is where the game starts.
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name) 

    current_scene.enter()
```

And here is the critical point to understand the whole game process:

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
```

Now you are inside the function CentralCorridor(), and you make your choices. Because your code is not complete, so in this case we assume action == 'shoot!' which gets you 'death' as a return value and passes this to next_scene_name. Now next_scene_name has been set to 'death'. You may have other scenes to be set if you make other choices here (if you code them).

Then

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

Set current_scene by searching the scene in class Map using the next_scene function which was explained earlier. In this case, searching the return from CentralCorridor() which is 'death', will get you the function death() in the library `scenes` located in class Map.

The game continues while loop as long as current_scene != last_scene. That's why you need a 'finished' scene in the scenes library.

Answer (score 1):

You call the `play()` function in the very last line of your code: `a_game.play()`

```
def opening_scene(self):
    # This call the next_scene method with the parameter start_scenes. 
    # which is initialize to 'central_corridor' when you create the object
    # with Map('central_corridor') a few lines below
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scenes) 


def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    # This get the value for key 'central_corridor' from 
    # the scenes dictionary and assign it to variable val.
    val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name) 
    return val
```

Comment: I understand next_scene gets the value of the key. But how is "return 'death'" going into next_scene of Map class?

Comment: There's a loop inside `play` method,  the get the return value of `enter` method and pass it into the map to get the next scene.

Comment: Ooh!! Yes! Now I understand. I totally overlooked that while loop there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To understand the code, you need to understand the last three lines of the code and what they actually do:

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

The object `a_map` is first created, which is-of class Map. Map is called with the argument central_corridor, which is a key to a dictionary that holds the value CentralCorridor(). CentralCorridor() is a class which inherits from the class Scene.

With this information, let's understand what the object `a_map` now actually holds. The object `a_map` can access everything within the class Map. The object also is directed to the class CentralCorridor and can access every method and variable there. Remember that CentralCorridor inherits from the class Scene, meaning it can also access variables and methods in Scene.

Now let's understand the object `a_game`. This object is an Engine class object. The Engine class, on the other hand, has the argument a_map. The a_map, as we have seen, is an object that can access various methods and variables in a number of classes as discussed above. It is now possible to access the play method in Engine, i.e. `a_game.play()`. Keenly this can help you understand and respond to your first questions. Just take time to understand how everything merges out and connects to each other.

On the second question, in fact, a proper understanding of the above can help you understand how everything couples up in the Engine class. `return self.next_scene(self.start_scenes)`holds the initial argument `central_corridor`. After executing the next value that is picked by the code `val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)` Therefore, the code `return val` takes the code to the new scene, which is the class Death.